# Windows key on the keyboard stoppped working

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Windows key on my keyboard has suddenly stopped working. This is not the first time it happened. I have managed to fix it last time by holding/clicking some special key or multiple keys on the keyboard and that "enabled" the windows key again.

I am sure I have accidentally clicked or hold some key again that cause the windows key to be disabled.
(There is no win lock key one my keyboard)

I have tried looking up which special key or combination of keys disable/enable the windows key but I cannot find it anywhere. Perhaps anyone knows about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried cleaning (carefully) the keyboard, and especially under this key?

Comment: Yes. It is as clean as it gets. As I mentioned before, the exact same thing happened before (maybe like 6 months ago) and I have managed to "unblock" it by clicking or holding something on the keyboard, I just cant remember what it was! :(

Comment: Its most likely a special key such as fn and the winkey itself. If you tell us the brand and type of your keyboard, we can look up what the keyboard combination is.

Comment: They keyboard is SteelSeries Apex 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your keyboard apparently has a "steel series" key, hold it and tap the windows key.

Source of information below.

[Apex 3 windows key not working](https://www.reddit.com/r/steelseries/comments/1050j3m/apex_3_windows_key_not_working/)

Never seen one, but apparently you are not the only one to have this issue.

Comment: Redundant but necessary if the link were to stop working. Quoting and citing external resources, and providing an explanation if necessary, is how good answers are created. I have nothing else to say on the matter. I thought  making it clear what the original suggestion actually was, including the fact pressing it again, would disable the Windows key would be a welcome improvement to the answer

Comment: The post reads what to do on the first line, link or not?  The edit said the same thing again...That makes no sense even if the link stopped working the solution is IN the post, the link was just for reference...